# Facing Issue with HTML markup

Tags: java, html, wicket

I'm trying to write a web-service based on Wicket. Now my code is not sophisticated, but the browser alerts me about an error on row 1, column 4.
What is the reason for it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org" xmlns:margin- 
top="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div wicket:id="menu" id="menu" style="width: 100%; text-align: justify">
    <a wicket:id="toTheory" href="Theory.html">Справка</a>
    <a wicket:id="toDirectoryInterface" 
href="DirectoryInterface.html">Хранилище шифрованных файлов</a>
</div>

<form wicket:id="form" style="width: 90%; height: 90%">
    <div style="position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 20%; /* (100% - width) / 2 */
  top: 5%;  /* (100% - height) / 2 */">
    <textarea  wicket:id = "text" height="90%" width="90%" rows="60" 
    cols="150"  id="text"/>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to fix everything, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Your html tag contains an invalid attribute: `xmlns:margin-top`

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org" xmlns:margin- 
top="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I guess it's a copy+paste error or similar, but the margin-top is a css attribute and can not be placed there. You might want to remove it and go with:

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```